# What version of SimpleDeclare do I need to run Booking Dojo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dojo

I'm trying to run the Booking Dojo project available at https://github.com/mercmobily/bookingdojo.
After running git clone, I ran:
$ npm install

NPM install does not install correctly simpleschema-tingo and simpledblayer-tingo, had to install them manually:
$ npm install simpledblayer-tingo
$ npm install simpleschema-tingo

After installing those modules, I tried to run again with the following commands:

```
$ node server
$ NODE_ENV='production' MONGO_URL="mongodb://$MONGO_USER:$MONGO_PASS@oceanic.mongohq.com:10082/$DBNAME" node server
```

These are the first lines from the trace dump (same error appears for both MongoDB and TingoDB):

```
/home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/bookingdojo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/mongo_client.js:424
              throw err
                    ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/bookingdojo/node_modules/simpledeclare/declare.js:137:57
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at declare (/home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/bookingdojo/node_modules/simpledeclare/declare.js:135:15)
    at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/bookingdojo/node_modules/bd/lib/bd.js:378:39
    at /home/bogdanbiv/WebstormProjects/bookingdojo/node_modules/hotplate/node_modules/hotCoreJsonRestStores/lib/hotCoreJsonRestStores.js:203:7
```

Full log is pasted into http://pastebin.com/DLV6fy71.
What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried: `export NODE_ENV='production'; export MONGO_URL="mongodb://$MONGO_USER:$MONGO_PASS@oceanic.mongohq.com:10082/$DBNAME"; node server`

Comment: Using, your command, export NODE_ENV='production'; export MONGO_URL="mongodb://$MONGO_USER:$MONGO_PASS@oceanic.mongohq.com:10082/$DBNAME"; node server appears to do something but then the process dies without any output.